# Making a program that zip files but having error The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program that will zip all the files in the same folder.
But I'm having issues with it. It's giving me an error saying the file is being used by another process.

```
Private Sub btnZip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZip.Click
        Dim extension As String = txtExtension.Text
        Dim paths As String = Application.StartupPath
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(paths, "*.*")
        For Each file As String In files
            Dim fileName As String = path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
            Dim index As Integer = fileName.IndexOf("_")
            If index >= 0 Then
                fileName = fileName.Substring(0, index)
            End If
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), paths & "\" & fileName & ".zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, False)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Files zipped successfully!")
    End Sub
```

I just couldn't figure out what's causing the issue.

Comment: It might not like the fact that your compressing the currently running application.

Comment: What would be the best practice to do the job? @CoolCoder123

Comment: If including the current executable is the problem then best practice would be to not include the current executable, don't you think? You need to get the list of files in that folder EXCEPT the current executable file. What efforts have you made to do that?

Answer (score 0):

as seen in comment, you must exclude your running application from the file list :
add

```
If Path.GetFileName(file) = Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) Then Continue For
```

in for loop

```
 Private Sub btnZip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZip.Click
        Dim extension As String = txtExtension.Text
        Dim paths As String = Application.StartupPath
        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(paths, "*.*")
        For Each file As String In files
            If Path.GetFileName(file) = Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) Then Continue For
            Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
            Dim index As Integer = fileName.IndexOf("_")
            If index >= 0 Then
                fileName = fileName.Substring(0, index)
            End If
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), paths & "\" & fileName & ".zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, False)
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Files zipped successfully!")
    End Sub
```